# googlemap release key didn't work, show blank map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

The map works well with debug key. After I generate a new api key with signed keystore, with this new release api key, the map is gone.

Here is my step:

1. with my signed keystore, use keytool to show SHA1 code.
2. with this SHA1 code and the package name, I go to Google APIs Console to generate a new api key.
3. I used this new api key in manifest.
4. Build the project.
5. Export signed application package.
6. Install this on my phone, the map become blank.

What's wrong with it?

Here is the manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wswsoft.mapdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
    android:name="com.wswsoft.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.wswsoft.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.wswsoft.mapdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data

android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

android:value=" AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


  <!-- body -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/map_fragment"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_below="@+id/loc_topbar"
android:layout_above="@+id/loc_bottombar">
<!-- Put fragments dynamically -->

</FrameLayout>     

 <!-- bottom bar component -->
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
     android:src="@drawable/bottombar" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:background="@drawable/half_button"
     android:text="定位" 
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:background="@drawable/half_button"
     android:text="继续" 
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/nextImg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:src="@drawable/next" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/locImg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:src="@drawable/location" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the activity code:

```
package com.wswsoft.mapdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {
            mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

            // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
            if (mMapFragment == null) {
                // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
                mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

                // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_fragment, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

            // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might
            // not be available.
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }
        Button locBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.locBtn);
        locBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
             showMap();         
         }
     });

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // mLocationSource.onResume();
}

private void showMap()
{
     // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
     Location mLocation;
     String sLong,sLat, sRange;

     if (mMap != null) {
            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);  

            // 高精度  
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);  
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);  
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);   
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);  
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            mLocation=mMap.getMyLocation();
            if (mLocation!=null)
            {
                sLat=Double.toString(mLocation.getLatitude());
                sLong=Double.toString(mLocation.getLongitude());
                sRange=Double.toString(mLocation.getAccuracy());
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                Log.i("location:Longitude",sLat);
                Log.i("location:Latitude",sLong);
                Log.i("location:Range",sRange);
                //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: `" AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"` here is a extra space. should be like `"AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I've deleted the extra space, but the map still show blank. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space in the following line:

```
android:value=" AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"
```

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"/>
```

**instead** of  `android:value=" AIzaSyD4hWWjxOV2zpM7hEJZK6pp4hmvBrN1AII"`

Comment: I've deleted the extra space, but the map still show blank. What else can I do?

Comment: you have problem with api key try by creating new one !

Comment: I've created several times. None is working. I also tried to change the package name, and generate a new key, but still not working.