# Example Google Maps for Android didn't work after debug

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded a Google Maps for Android project, it debugged (have an `apk` file). Install this file to device, it work well, but when I debug it with eclipse, it shows blank map. I putted into it my debug key, but I don't know how it don't work.

I saw a question with the same my problem, but it didn't solve problem
This is it:[googlemap release key didn't work, show blank map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848666/googlemap-release-key-didnt-work-show-blank-map).

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: I downloaded project from http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html
it was named AndroidMapsV2.apk